# How to run a single mocha test written in typescript in WebStorm 2016.1

Tags: webstorm

I setup a mocha "run configuration" for tests written in typescript and "run" command executes perfectly.

But when I choose to run a single test by click the "run ..." popup menu in the "run" window, syntax error occurs.

In the run window, WebStorm execute something like:

`/usr/local/bin/node /(...)/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha --ui bdd --reporter /Applications/(...)/mochaIntellijReporter.js /(...)/my-test.ts --grep "MyTest Basic test$"`

It seems that WebStorm passes `.ts` file instead of the generated `.js` file to mocha, and thus causes syntax errors.

Any ideas or workarounds?

Comment: Related issue in WebStorm tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21069

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a workaround, `.ts` files can be run instead of the generated `.js`: specify `--require ts-node/register` in "Extra Mocha options" field (and `npm install ts-node`).

Comment: ts-node advises to append the following flags: --compilers ts:ts-node/register,tsx:ts-node/register - both work

Comment: How to specify own tsconfig file in options